# Kill child process with cleanup

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a way to kill my app's child process and perform it's cleanup(calling deconstructors and atexit functions), similarly to `exit(exit_code)`, but on another process?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501522/how-to-kill-a-child-process-by-the-parent-process

Comment: @MareInfinitus that's unix, i need a windows implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on windows, you probably start your child processes by CreateProcess, which has a PROCESS_INFORMATION as the last parameter.

[CreateProcess on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Process Information on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Option 1:**

This process information contains a handle to the process started in the hProcess member.

You can store this handle and use it to kill your child processes.

**Insert**
You probably want to send WM_CLOSE and / or WM_QUIT?
to "cleanly" end the process:

Here is a KB Article on what to do [KB how to cleanly kill win32 processes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178893)

** End Insert**

**Option 2:**

Here is an discussion on how to properly kill a process tree: [Terminate a process tree on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173342/terminate-a-process-tree-c-for-windows)

Comment: `ExitProcess` kills the process which called it, i need to kill the child from the parent, and `TerminateProcess` doesn't perform cleanup!

Comment: As you do not provide information on how this processes are spawned and what kind of process they are, it is somewhat difficult. Sending a WM_CLOSE may be okay, or a GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent() could do the job.

Comment: I use `CreateProcess` and im interested in a universal way of doing this, unlike `WM_CLOSE/WM_QUIT` which assumes that the process has a window

Comment: you should really try out WM_CLOSE. this is the gentle way of closing an application as seen here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx if that application does not support WM_CLOSE, and not WM_QUIT, TerminateProcess may be the last resort.

Comment: I'll try that out, then i guess there is no universal way of doing this, thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple Win32 API for that kind of thing. The OS doesn't care what language your program's source code was written in, the compiled program appears to it as just a sequence of CPU instructions plus data.

The cleanest way would be to establish some kind of a communication channel between the processes (e.g. via shared memory) and simply request process termination.

You can achieve the same by starting the child process as a debugged process and then using debug APIs to alter the child's behavior, but that's too intrusive and not very straightforward to implement.

Comment: The simplest and cheapest "communication channel" for this is a named event.

Comment: @arx i can't do this, the child process isn't written by me