# How to kill child of fork?

Tags: c, fork

I have the following code which create a child fork. And I want to kill the child before it finish its execution in the parent. how to do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int i;

main (int ac, char **av)
{
  int pid;

  i = 1;

  if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    /* child */
    while (1) {
      printf ("I m child\n");
      sleep (1);
    }
  }
  else {
    /* Error */
    perror ("fork");
    exit (1);
  }
  sleep (10)

   // TODO here: how to add code to kill child??

}
```

Comment: `fork()` returns a `pid_t`, not an `int`, so you should declare your variable as such.

Comment: Unrelated to the original question: When fork returns a new process is spawned (in case of success) and both parent and child continue execution from the point where `fork` has been called. pid = 0 for a child process (well, it can always get it via getpid()) and pid > 0 for a parent process. The error is only when fork returns -1. In your code you are treating a "parent process" part as an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to kill a child process by the parent process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501522/how-to-kill-a-child-process-by-the-parent-process)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Send a signal.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

kill(pid, SIGKILL);

/* or */

kill(pid, SIGTERM);
```

The second form preferable, among other, if you'll handle signals by yourself.

Comment: or `SIGTERM`, if you want to be more polite :)

Comment: Why does everyone insist on SIGKILLs ?

Comment: @Niklas B.: Is there any advantage to use `SIGTERM` here? As far I can see, he doesn't have any handler.

Comment: @Kirilenko - One assumes that this Noddy example is just to gain understanding. In the real world the child process would be more complex than this.

Answer (score 16):

See [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) system call. Usually a good idea to use SIGTERM first to give the process an opportunity to die gratefully before using SIGKILL.

**EDIT**

Forgot you need to use [waitpid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) to get the return status of that process and prevent zombie processes.

**A FURTHER EDIT**

You can use the following code:

```
kill(pid, SIGTERM);

bool died = false;
for (int loop; !died && loop < 5 /*For example */; ++loop)
{
    int status;
    pid_t id;
    sleep(1);
    if (waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG) == pid) died = true;
}

if (!died) kill(pid, SIGKILL);
```

It will give the process 5 seconds to die gracefully

Answer (score 5):

Issue `kill(pid, SIGKILL)` from out of the parent.