# Can Parent Process terminate without executing the Child Process?

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, parent-child, system-calls

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    //fork();
    //printf("Hello World\n");
    int i=fork();
        // child process because return value zero
    if (i == 0)
        printf("Hello from Child! %d \n",i);
 
    // parent process because return value non-zero.
    if (i!=0)
        printf("Hello from Parent! %d \n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Why the first output is giving two print output while other are only giving outputs from the Parent Only - when fork() creates two processes.

I am expecting two output print in each output case because of the existence of two process.

Can anyone explain why ?

Output 1:

```
Hello from Parent! 600 
Hello from Child! 0
```

Output 2:

```
Hello from Parent! 8206
```

Output 3:

```
Hello from Parent! 350
```

Output 4:

```
Hello from Parent! 1098
```

Why the first output is giving two print output while other are only giving single outputs from the Parent Only - when fork() creates two processes. I am expecting two output print in output case.

Comment: Can't reproduce.... I get both prints every time I run the program

Comment: You might want to `wait` until the child exits (and the child should probably exit explicitly, not just return from `main`).

Comment: What operating system?  What compiler?  What compiler options?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the child process is successfully terminated. You can run additional code to ensure the child process is terminated before the parent process.

```
int pid = fork();
//...............
kill(pid, SIGKILL);
```

EDIT:
See this answer: [How to kill child of fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273836/how-to-kill-child-of-fork)

Comment: How would doing this change whatever string the child process prints?  Outside of killing it before it printed anything?

Comment: I figured any call to fork() after the first child process is created will not create a new process, since an identical child process is already running. Killing the child process before exiting parent process would ensure that won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Given this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    //fork();
    //printf("Hello World\n");
    int i=fork();
        // child process because return value zero
    if (i == 0)
        printf("Hello from Child! %d \n",i);
 
    // parent process because return value non-zero.
    if (i!=0)
        printf("Hello from Parent! %d \n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

if `fork()` were to fail, it would generate the output you're seeing.

This code will tell you *why* `fork()` fails:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    //fork();
    //printf("Hello World\n");
    pid_t i=fork();
    if (i < 0)
        perror( "fork() failed" );
        // child process because return value zero
    if (i == 0)
        printf("Hello from Child! %d \n",( int ) i);
 
    // parent process because return value non-zero.
    if (i!=0)
        printf("Hello from Parent! %d \n", ( int ) i);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, note that `fork()` returns `pid_t`, not `int`.  They don't have to be the same.