# error: ‘SIGKILL’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, fork, kill

Alright, I was trying to make a simple function to constantly change its PID, 
but I get this:

```
error: ‘SIGKILL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int changePID(void) {
        int pid = fork();
        printf(pid);
        sleep(3);
        kill(pid, SIGKILL);
}

    int main(void) {
        while (1) {
            changePID();
            }
}
```

Comment: This also may help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501522/how-to-kill-a-child-process-by-the-parent-process

Comment: #include <signal.h>
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal+2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are missing the line `#include <signal.h>`  for the SIGKILL

`printf(pid);` is not going to work since printf need a `char*` and you give him a `pid_t`

What's the point of killing a child in a loop ?

printf is going to segv in the father so you will never reach kill

and in the son you are going to kill

> every process in the process group of the current process with a pid of 0

Comment: `pid_t`comes implicitly with `@include`ing `<unistd.h>` which prototypes `fork()` and `sleep()`.

Comment: doesn't work on windows. I had to hardcode 9

Answer (score 2):

You need to add:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
```

Look at the man page when you have an issue with a system call.

Comment: Working now, although I had to fix a few other errors it is fine, thanks!

Comment: Why include `<sys/types.h>`?

Comment: +1 for talking about the manpage. It seems that nobody looks at the manpages anymore in 2013...

Answer (score 0):

try to include

```
#define <sys/signal.h>
```